# the difference between "with time", "over time", "during time"

Tags: meaning, word-choice

what is the difference between the following sentences, and which one is preferable in what occasions:
Its characteristics changes with time 
Its characteristics changes during time 
Its characteristics changes over time

Comment: You need a verb in the singular.

Comment: @Lambie True, but *characteristics* could be singular, too, sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"With time" is best used to imply a relationship: the position of a vehicle moving or accelerating at a constant speed changes with time. It also changes over time, but "with" invites a follow-up question about the process, whereas "over" invites a follow-up about the result.

"Over time" also has an historic flavor.   A lawyer seeks to attract clients over time, rather than with time. Again, there is no mathematical relationship, even metaphorically, between the ticking clock and the events described.

"During time" is not used English. "During [a specific time]" is used: "Its characteristics changed during *the* time that he was gone."  (But "while" would suffice.)

Comment: I'm new here, but I will admit that I am put off by unexplained downvotes, especially for an answer that the owner has accepted.  Can someone explain why they dinged my answer here?

Comment: I find this answer helpful and as accurate as it gets.

Answer (score -1):

- Its characteristics change **with** time  -- concurrently
- Its characteristics change **during** time  -- (is not used -- "during time" does not make sense but "during something else" can be used).
- Its characteristics change **over** time  --  sometime, anytime, once or many times or continuously